# Can we assign a ViewModel to a ViewData object in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

The question seems strange but I am using the DevExpress library and I need to send my own object (a viewmodel) to a controller action via a DevExpress `BeginCallback` event.

Basically I have a simple and advance search, the simple search works prefectly as that is only a string value

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult DevExpressGridView(string simple, AdvanceSearch adv)
    {
          ViewData["data"] = simple;
         ..Search Logic
    }
```

So when the Gridview is populated, I want to double click on a row in order to fetch the item from the database

```
    function CallBack(s, e) {

        e.customArgs['simple'] = "@ViewData["data"]";
    }
```

lastly the Gridview Action method

```
  @Html.Action("DevExpressGridView", new { simple = @ViewData["data"] })
```

But if the user wants to do an AdvanceSearch which is my own ViewModel, how could I send the data back via the callback? If possible at all?

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult DevExpressGridView(string simple, AdvanceSearch adv)
    {
          ViewData["data"] = adv;
         // Its my own type so it can't work can it?
    }
```

*I would ask the DevExpress support team but I am still getting my license so they won't help until then*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewData` is of type `ViewDataDictionary` which implements `IDictionary<string,object>`, as you can see from the [relevant msdn documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx). So you can store any type of object in it, although I would personally instead prefer to return a viewmodel in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, i totally agree, but how do you send a Viewmodel back via an @Html.Action method?

     @Html.Action("DevExpressGridView", new { simple = "TEST", Model })

Model just reinitalise the data, I need the current data that is within the viewmodel to go back

Comment: Assuming the view's model type is `AdvanceSearch`, have you tried `@Html.Action("DevExpressGridView", new { simple = "TEST", adv = Model })`?

Comment: Instead of adv = model would be  adv =ViewData["..."] right?

Comment: In the case you're using `ViewData` yes, it would be so, but you may need to cast this to `AdvanceSearch`.

Comment: Can I do this in a view? (razor)

Comment: Yes you can, but this is one of the reasons I suggested using a viewmodel instead. Did you try it without the cast?

Comment: I did and it comes as a new initialised object. Not sure if DevExpress allows you do pass your own objects in from the view..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62978/discussion-between-elolos-and-user3428422).